# Multiple coins after currency fork

Tags: blockchain-fork

Situation: bitcoin hardforks and I got payment with coins, that were in the blockchain before fork:

what can prevent me for sending the same transaction to the other forked network and get the second forked money, because I have a signed sending transaction and I own the target address private keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from doing such.  You now own coins on both chains, and can spend them independently. Assuming that adequate [replay protection](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/61212/what-is-transaction-replay-and-replay-protection) has been implemented, you shouldn't have to worry about your transaction on one network being broadcast without your consent on the other.